# Is there an R function to create a cross-sell matrix for x products and y-length combinations of them?

Tags: r

I made a similar post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887259/cross-sell-matrix-in-postgresql)

I'm now considering if and how this can be done in R.

What I am trying to achieve is a matrix with columns representing standalone products (x), rows representing the combinations of the products in those columns (y), and each cell representing a count of occurrences where there is a cross-sell occurring.

[Image of sample data in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM7d6.png)

Copy and paste sample data from the CSV:

customer,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,
101,1,1,,,1,,,1,,,1,
102,2,,1,,,,,,,,,
103,3,,,1,,,1,,,1,,
104,4,,1,,,,,,,,,1
105,5,,1,,,,,,,,,1
106,6,,,,1,,,,,,,
107,7,,,1,,,,,,,,
108,8,1,1,,1,,,,,,,
109,9,,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,
110,10,,1,,,,,,1,,,

Ideally I would like to have something that shows number of customers that buy specific product combinations (say up to 4 different products for now), such as customers 103 and 109 buying products D+G+J.

I appreciate the matrix could be quite large with 231 unique product combinations, but is this possible in R?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What would you want your output to look like?

Comment: So column headers would be products A to K, then row headers would be every product combination from A to HIJK, being the final 4-product combination. Where product A and product A cross, it would be zero, but where product A and product B cross it would show the number that showed a customer bought both A and B.

Using my previous sample data, customers 101 and 108 both bought A and D, so where A and D crossed, it would show 2.

Am I making sense?